# Are these algorithm implemented in Objective-C Libraries?

Tags: objective-c, full-text-search

I want to know, Are these algorithms implemented in Objective-C Libraries for text search?

1. Knutt-Morri-Pratt
2. Boyer-Moore
3. finite automata

Comment: By "Objective-C Libraries," do you mean "Foundation," "third-party libraries that use the standard Foundation classes," "any library compatible with Objective-C" or what?

Comment: There are text search methods such as `NSString rangeOfString:`. But the documentation doesn't say how they're implemented.

Comment: actually i want to search a sentence(consist of 2 or 3 words) in a huge passage. do you think (NSString rangeOfString) is responsible for this task?

Comment: no, haven't tried it yet. just trying to gather info about at, because i am writing a proposal now, not implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for CFStringFindWithOptionsAndLocale in [CFString.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFString.c), it seems like it only implements naive search. Depending on how huge the text is, you might actually get away with this.

Regardless, if your passage is sufficiently huge, Boyer-Moore and KMP are still linear time (albeit with a smaller constant factor), you might want to look at implementing a simple disk based full text index. I've done it for a client's project and it really isn't as hard as it sounds.